# Redraw customized google maps javascript map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm really new to JS..
My website theme came with integrated custom google maps.

So i want that when i press on one of four buttons buttons, it reloads coordinates to different predefined ones.

So far I only managed to change the coordinates but it doesn't redraw the map to the new location with the marker.

So for example this is JS code to switch maps cordinates

```
function jumptomap4() { 
var element = document.getElementById("kordinates"); 
element.setAttribute("data-coordinates", "[[55.873744, 26.513021]]"); 
}
```

Map container:

```
<div id="kordinates" class="map-container" data-coordinates="[[56.955152, 24.154613]]" data-icon='"images/assets/map-marker.png"' data-info='"Information text"' data-zoom-level="16" data-style="greyscale">
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
```

And this is the button that should change coordinates and redraw map..

```
<a onClick="jumptomap4();" href="#kordinates">
<button class="small bkg-red bkg-hover-red color-white">Skatīt kartē</button>
</a>
```

Could someone please help me figure this out!? :)

Comment: Is this all your own custom code or is a part of the theme?

Comment: Only the function jumptomap4 is mine.. Rest is part of template.. Here is template .js file - https://jsfiddle.net/vautinsh/akh3fgrb/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried re-sizing the map using *'google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');'* you can also use 'panTo(latLng:LatLng|LatLngLiteral)'. Based on the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map), changes the center of the map to the given '**LatLng**'. If the changes is less than both the width and height of the map, the transition will be smoothly animated.